# Select attributes in a column that are similar to attributes from another column

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select

I have two map layers. One layer contains names of roads, on which some road accident occures. Those are the roads from whole region. The road names on this layer also contains the km or the number of a house, on which accident happend.

[image]

On the other layer I have names of roads only from the regional road network.

[image]

You can see that the recording method is very different. Now what I need is to select roads from the layer 1, that have the same name as on layer 2. I was thinking about using LIKE function, but I only found how to use it ones per attribute.

Comment: Can you add an example of which expression you have used? Also, in the images, I can't see any matching attribute. Can you show some example of matching attributes?

Comment: I've edited first screenshot. You can see that first and second lists have Leonessa street, for example. Whole list is huge, I have 3000 lines in first layer and around 120 streets is the second one. So to clarify, I need to select lines from first table with the names from second table. I haven't used any expression yet, I just found that I can use LIKE function if I need to select something that has not exact name as other feature. But I need to use it not for 1 feature but for the whole list.

Comment: This sounds like you might need to explore a Virtual Layer using SQL to do the iLIKE join.